# Co-ordinate geometry involving straight lines $7x-y-32 = 0$ and $3y-2x+1=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> Let $P$ be the point of intersection of the lines $7x-y-32=0$ and $3y-2x+1=0$. Lines are drawn through $P$ making intercepts of equal magnitude on the co-ordinate axes. Find the equation of these lines.

This is what I have done till now: first finding the point of intersection which I get as ($5,3$). Then I let the $x$-intercept of the line be '$a$'. So its $y$- intercept is also '$a$'. Therefore, its equation is $x+y=a$. Now ($5,3$) lies on the line, so substituting $x=5$ and $y=3$ implies $a=8$. So the equation is $x+y=8$. Now how do I proceed?

Comment: It would be useful for you to edit your original question to include the work you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "intercepts of equal magnitude"?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more to proceed, you are done ok!

EDIT

From your description I take it that you include its sign also.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the equations of lines: $7x-y-32=0$ & $-2x+3y+1=0$ we get the intersection point $P(5, 3)$

Now, let the equal intercepts of the lines be $k$ with the coordinate axes then the equation of lines $$\frac{x}{k}+\frac{y}{k}=1$$  $$x+y=k$$ but the line passes through the point $P(5, 3)$ hence it will satisfy the above equation as follows $$5+3+k$$ $$k=8$$ Hence, substituting the value of $k=8$ we get equation of lines $$\color{blue}{x+y=8}$$ The above result shows that there is only a single line passing through the point $P(5, 3)$ & intercepting equal length $8$ with the axes.

Your result is absolutely OK.